# Update prices in in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, opencart

1. I have a LibreOffice Calc file with two columns: `id | new_price`
2. My OpenCart database table is called `product` and has these relevant columns: `id | price`

I need to update `price` in database based on `id` in the Calc file with the value in `new_price`.

I have phpmyadmin available, but I am not sure how to do this.

Could You please guide me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the file into a new table using import function in phpmyadmin, let's say called `new_table` and then execute:

```
UPDATE 
    product
SET 
    price = 
    (
        SELECT 
            new_price 
        FROM 
            new_table 
        WHERE 
            new_table.id = product.product_id
    )
WHERE
    product.product_id IN 
    (
        SELECT
            id
        FROM
            new_table
    )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

I did this on a test copy of my db. It had the unwanted effect, that ALL prices in old_table that is not in new_table was set to 0 ....

Comment: @user2298034 I have edited the query, check it now - it should work.

Comment: Thanke for updating the script. But still it has the unwanted effect that all products not existing in new_table are given price = 0.

Comment: I added a `WHERE` part to the script to get rid of the unwanted effect. Many ways were available, but this probably is the easiest one :) Hopefully, now everything works for you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Problem solved :) Very nice of you to help out.

Comment: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: @KasparL.Palgi that means you have duplicate data in new table. Either remove duplicates or take first/last/min/max/etc based on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

OK, You have multiple options how to achieve this.

1. Write an import/update script in PHP that will load the CSV (XML, TXT - use the one that You are familiar with...) file (created from Your Calc file) and update all the products in a loop...
2. Same as 1. but instead of CSV You would use the original XLS file with appropriate XLS parser...
3. Using `phpMyAdmin` import the file into a new (temporary) table and run a query to update the products using values from the new temporary table - for query check **Andrius's answer**.

Let's say You'd stick with the first option (as the third is already answered and the second one is very similar using the right parser) and that the final CSV file looks like this:

```
1;25.900
3;19.990
11;5.250
...
```

Now You just need to load the file and use [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) function - check the PHP doc to understand how to use it. In the while loop just call this SQL query:

```
$query = "UPDATE `" . DB_PREFIX . "product` SET `price` = {$line[1]} WHERE `product_id` = {$line[0]}";
```

assuming that in Your while loop a `$line` is one line from the CSV file that is being currently read.

You can then use the script as a new controller (within it's `index` action`) or just add this to Your existing product controller as a new action...

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping out, shadyyx. I think method 3 is most relevant now - but with #1 I could make it easier to update prices in the future. 

The problem still is that the query in #3 still updates ALL prices. new_prices only has a sub set of the total products. And all products not included in new_prices are set to 0....

Comment: @user2298034 Andrius has added a `WHERE` condition that should solve the problem definitely ;-) Yes, the `#1` solution is *re-usable* in the future while with `#3` You would have to clean and re-import the data everytime...

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it sorted now. You have all been very helpful.

Comment: @user2298034 Then go and hit +1 for what was helpful for You ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You need to learn how to read files in php. You need to extract the price of every id and update it into database. Learn about [file-get-contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function.

Comment: Your answer brings no light on the solution. Using `file_get_contetns()` is really not enough. Try improving You answer!

Answer (score -2):

Load data and insert into your OpenCart table

LOAD DATA INFILE '../LibreOffice_Calc.txt' INTO TABLE OpenCart

Comment: This will try to insert new values. If he'd used this for `product` table this would lead into error. Try improving Your answer...